# Excel VBA format

Tags: excel, vba

i have a sheet where i connect to SQL. how can i create vba where every time i click refresh data connection query from power query, it will convert my text to number. Once it convert, i would like to format it to percentage and some are in accounting format. Upon refresh again, the same format will stick as it is without need to click format again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, by using onChange event in VBA:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: Hi, I try applying this code below:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With Target
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub

After apply, the refresh data query is not working. I need to load back again. Any idea what is wrong?